# Latex. Подпись к таблице по центру

Tags: вёрстка, latex

Дано. Таблица в Latex. В последней объединенной строке нет левой границе. Что не так? Убей не пойму. Ну и сразу. Как сделать так чтобы подпись к таблице тоже была по центру, как и сама таблица?

```
%................ТАБЛИЦА.9.....................................
%..............................................................
\hfil
\begin{table}[hb]
\begin{center}
%разметка
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.22\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.11\textwidth}|}
\hline 
%Заголовок
\centering{Вид помехи} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Значение параметров} & Базовый стандарт & Примеч. \\ 
\hline
%1 строка
\centering Радиочастоты общий режим & 0,15МГц…80МГц
10В 80\% ЧМ, 1КГц & \centering Немодулируемый сигнал & \centering МЭК 61000-4-6 & \centering 1 \arraybackslash \\ \hline
%2 строка
\centering {Быстрый переходный процесс} & \centering $\pm$2кВ\\* 5/50нс\\* 5КГц & \centering Повторяемая частота & \centering МЭК 61000-4-4 & \centering \\* 2 \arraybackslash \\ \hline
%3 строка
\centering Помехи & \centering 1,2/50 мкс\\*$\pm$2кВ 42Ом, 0,5мкФ\\*$\pm$1кВ 42Ом, 0,5мкФ & \centering По цепи «провод-земля» По цепи «провод-провод» & \centering МЭК 61000-4-5 & \centering \\* 3 \arraybackslash \\ \hline
%последняя строка-объединение 5 столбцов+длинный нумерованный текст
\multicolumn{5}{10 cm}{Тестовый уровень эквивалентен току при нагрузке 150 Ом. Прямая связь. Прямая и обратная полярность. 3.Это испытание позволяет повторить явление, известное как прямая связь, поэтому рекомендуется выходное сопротивление 42Ом(40Ом и 2Ом генератора) и емкость 0,5 мкФ.
} \\
\cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
\caption {Помехоустойчивость. Порты по питанию}
\end{center}
\end{table}
%..............................................................
%................ТАБЛИЦА.9.....................................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что такое

```
\multicolumn{5}{10 cm}
```

?

Наверное, вы имели в виду

```
\multicolumn{5}{|p{10 cm}|}
```

Место подписи к таблице определяется стилем, а не вами, вы не должны пытаться переопределить его вручную.

(И кстати, вы бы запостили *минимальный* пример, а не всё подряд.)

Answer (score 0):

Если под подписью к таблице имелось ввиду `\caption {Помехоустойчивость. Порты по питанию}`, то есть следующее решение:

В преамбуле необходимо указать:

```
\usepackage{caption} %заголовки плавающих объектов
\captionsetup[table]{justification=centering} %установки для заголовков таблиц
```